# How to add autocomplete functionality for Listpicker in windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker, autocompletebox

Hi I'm developing wp8 application .

I'm using List picker for bind city names.Below it's my code for list Picker

XAML

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Lpcity" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="400,10,0,0"  Height="80" Width="50" Visibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="Lpcity_SelectionChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/search.png"/>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.Background>

            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding cityname}"  Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Red"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30">
                        <Run Text="{Binding cityname}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

C#

```
 public void Citybind()
    {
       string city_nameurl = "http://xxxx.yyyyy";
        WebClient city_namewc = new WebClient();

        city_namewc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(city_nameurl), UriKind.Relative);
        city_namewc.DownloadStringCompleted += city_namewc_DownloadStringCompleted;
     }


  void city_namewc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      var city_name = e.Result;
            city_namedata add = new city_namedata();
            add.id = "-1";
            add.cityname = "Select any one city";
            add.id = "0";
            add.cityname = "Remove city based search";
            var city_nameval = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<city_namedata>>(city_name);
            city_nameval.Insert(0, add);
            Lpcity.ItemsSource = city_nameval;
        }
```

OutPut:

[image]

Now nearly 200 and more city name is bind in List picker. If user wan to select city name start with z. now he need to scroll to the bottom of the screen.

So i need to add the auto complete functionality . If user type z all z related name should show to user.

I searched in web and find out autocomplete box functionality.I try with following code for autocomplete box

XAML

```
 <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                             Width="450" 
                             Grid.Row="0"                                    
                             Name="autoCompleteBox1"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             InputScope="Digits"
                             ItemsSource="{StaticResource AutoCompletions}"
                             />
```

[image]

Now i need to know it's possible to add both list picker and autocomplete box?

Other wise any other option available for my requirement?

Thank you

Comment: have you got any solution regarding this issue.I am also stuck with same issue.If you have plz reply